# Diagnostic for Finiteness

Tags: tense, aspect, malay

For a language that does not have overt morphological tense and any tense distinctions (e.g. Malay), how is it possible to discern whether a clause is finite or non-finite? Is it possible to use aspectual markers as a diagnostic for finiteness and say that a clause that does not permit aspectual markers is non-finite?

```
Saya biar dia  (*akan) makan
1.SG let  3.SG (*PROS) eat

Saya mahu (*akan) makan
1.SG want (*PROS) eat
```

Are subjunctive and imperative clauses finite? In English, the verb form used in subjunctives is unconjugated, so it's tempting to say that at least subjunctives are non-finite. It's less clear for imperatives though, because of the 2nd person.

The examples below do not permit prospective aspect marker 'will'.

```
I recommend that he (*will) choose this option.

(*Will) choose this option!
```

Answer (score 1):

Look to see if it has a subject.  Clauses with subjects are finite; those without subjects are nonfinite.  This criterion was once proposed by my friend Stan Starosta.  Works for me, for English, though I think he intended it more generally.

Comment: _For me to leave early would be a mistake_ has an infinitive clause with a marked subject, but I'd have to say it was non-finite. I agree with Yellow Sky that finiteness is irrelevant for Malay, as I imagine it would be for Mandarin. And in Malay subjecthood is not a simple concept; only subjects may be relativized, for instance, but all relative clauses are introduced by the same morpheme (_yang_) and there are no relative pronouns. So it looks like _yang_ is the subject, but it's not, really.

Comment: @jlawler I can't decipher your comment that *for me to leave early* has a "marked subject".  What's a "marked subject"?  Is it a subject?  If so, what I said is wrong.  If it means a non-subject which has the interpretation of a subject, then what I said may be correct. // Assuming what I said is right, finitenes is relevant in Malay, provided Malay distinguishes between clauses with and without subjects.

Comment: In an infinitive, _for_ marks a(n unRaised) subject NP and _to_ marks the VP. It sounds like you're insisting that infinitives have no subjects, but rather another kind of NP with all of the properties of subjects. As for Malay, "subject" doesn't mean the same thing as it does in English (if it means anything -- Indonesian-style GRs run to three NP types, not two as in erg or acc systems), and I don't know any way Malay distinguishes clauses that way. It's an interesting idea, but I don't think "subject" is a universal property.

Comment: @jlawler Two tests commonly used to determine English subjects are whether you get the subjective forms of pronouns and whether verbs agree in number.  It's not just me.  Of course, the "for" objects of infinitives satisfy neither test.  So it's very puzzling why you would say they have "all the properties of subjects".

Comment: Those are properties of the clause types, which has to be what finitude refers to, if it refers to anything. By "subject" in English I normally refer to what would be a `1` in Arc Pair grammar; for me it's a semantactic category, and morphology, like preposition choice, complement type, and most everything else variable, is particular to the clause type and predicate type, and not a criterial property.

Comment: @jlawler A "1" in Arc Pair grammar is a property of an arc.  An arc is not a clause (its head may be a clause).  So a "1" is not a property of a clause.

Comment: I don't necessarily have any use for the formalization of the nodes and arcs; I see no purpose to excessive detail in a descriptive grammar. Like Jim, I'm perfectly happy to steal a concept from one formalization or another without being required to buy a completely new matched set of labels.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of finite/infinite verb forms is definitely irrelevant for Malay since the Malay verbs have *no* forms at all. As for English, if a verb form can be a predicate and it can be the only verb form inside the clause, then it is a finite verb form.

Comment: By that standard, English infinitives are finite. This seems unfortunate.

Comment: @jlawler - Sorry? Can you give an example where the predicate is expressed by an infinitive and that's the only verb form inside the clause?

Comment: @YellowSky You ask *jlawler to answer*. In the italicized clause the infinitive *to answer* is the entire predicate and the only verb form.

Comment: @StoneyB - Nonsense! _jlawer_ is no way the subject, that's a direct object, it can be easily seen if you substitute _jlawer_ with a personal pronoun: I ask _him_ to answer. _Him_ is probably the logical subject of _to answer_, but the point is that _him to answer_ is not a clause, that's an objective infinitive complex.

Comment: @YellowSky To embrace your style of argument, Poppycock! . . . *him to answer* is the clausal complement of the verb *ask*--what you ask is that he answer--with its subject cast in object case because *ask* is a 'control' verb like *want* or *expect*.

Comment: @StoneyB - The OP's question is about formal criteria. Formally, _him to answer_ is not a clause since it lacks a nominative case subject. To embrace your style of argument, _his answer_ is also a clause, he answers, and in this clause _answer_ is the predicate expressed by a noun. )))

Comment: In most syntactic theories that are still relevant/useful, **clauses can be both finite or non-finite.** The very term "objective infinitive complex" reminds me of Soviet linguistics research in the 1950-1960s (or European linguistics of the nineteenth century).

Comment: In _You asked `X` to answer_, `X` is both the indirect object of _ask_ **and** the subject of the infinitive _answer_. `X` only occurs once in the sentence because of the equivalence of the two NPs (or because of the identity of the node that the two grammatical relations both point to, if you prefer that formalization). Technically, this is called [***Equi***](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf), and _ask_ is a 3-place verb governing B-Equi. So `X` has both relations and is conveniently placed for both of them. English syntax is clever.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, many grammarians agree that the idea of finite/infinite verb forms is not applicable when the language lacks enough verb inflections (usually an analytic language). However, some grammars argue that aspectual markers can help to distinguish finite verbs from non-finite verbs.

Your second question has been discussed in A COMPHRENSIVE GRAMMAR OF THE ENGLISH LANGUAGE.
[image]

[image]
 1. List item

Comment: Well, in order to use unmarked voice, mood, or aspect to categorize finite from non-finite, we have to posit a number of further categories that have problematic existence, like "subjunctive". Since the only difference between non-finite infinitives and finite "subjunctives", according to the chart, is that the "subjunctives" are "in the subjunctive mood", while the infinitives are not, there are certain problems with the logic.