# Must subjectless infinitives exhibit subject control when used as complements(traditionally direct objects) of other verbs?

Tags: syntax, grammar, list-of-languages

In English, the answer will be yes in most cases, but [one thesis](https://tampub.uta.fi/bitstream/handle/10024/82435/gradu04955.pdf?sequence=1) cast doubt on this. The author provided an example taken from BNC:

- My mother helped [PRO] to cater for the funeral tea, which were community affairs with everyone helping. (BN6 1505)

[Another treatise](https://books.google.com/books?isbn=082046399X) provided some examples which seemed more convinicing (you can google them):

- She motioned to be quiet.
- She signalled to open the gates and let them in.

Besides, I doubt if this rule works in other languages.

Comment: If one accepts James Huang's controversial finiteness distinction in Chinese, then the 'help' example is valid in Chinese as well.

Comment: As for Chinese verbs, finite verbs and non-finite verbs are distinguished syntactically rather than morphologically, because Chinese verbs do not have plenty of morphological changes, which is unlike many other languages. Chinese verbs are nearly only inflected for aspects. Chinese is an analytic language (also known as isolating language). So I would say the distinction would be meaningless.

Comment: However, we can regard infinitval clauses as semantic entities. Bolinger proposed a principle used to show semantic differences between an infinitive and a gerund when they have same syntactic function in English: a infinitive expresses something 'hypothetical, future, unfulfilled' whereas the gerund typically expresses something 'real, vivid, fulfilled'. We may use this principle to find "semantic infinitival clauses" in languages that lack such inflections. However, this principle fails when the verb is "to manage" or "to get".

Comment: I wouldn't say the distinction is meaningless. Huang and supporters of his distinction, like Audrey Li, did use this distinction to explain why aspect markers cannot be used in certain embedded clauses. (There are legitimate concerns with the distinction as outlined by linguists like Xu Liejiong, and there is no clear consensus yet.) In any case, I think that *if* the finiteness distinction exists, it does further support your objection, since the help construction can be constructed similarly in Chinese (subjectless infinitives, complements of verbs, object control).

Comment: But one would be restricted to certain help-related verbs. 幫忙 and 幫手 come to mind (though I'm not sure if the latter can be used that way in Standard Chinese - it certainly can in Cantonese.)

Comment: Yes, some research has been conducted to study why aspectual markers must not appear in some constructions. [Another post](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/17522/diagnostic-for-finiteness) may be helpful. In Mandarin, the equivalents are 帮 and 帮助. 帮忙 is an intransitive verb, though occasionally it is used transitively, but it sounds unnatural. 帮手 is a noun in Mandarin, which means "helper".

Comment: Chinese verbs lack morphological distinction betweem finite verbs and non-finite verbs, which caused trouble for early grammarians. (they studied Chinese with Latinate grammar)

Comment: In addition, gerunds(not infinitives) may not exhibit subject control, such as gerunds after the verb"to recommend".

Comment: CORRECTION: 帮忙 can be either transitive or intransitive. It is followed by a verbal phrase when used transitively (occasionally followed by a phrase indicating person, but it sounds unnatural).

Comment: I'm actually thinking about examples like these:
我幫(他)忙把桌子移到臥室, 
我幫(佢)手將張檯移返睡房 -
which seem to follow the same pattern as in your first example (except the normal positioning of the object).